# Insert trigger preventing duplicates

Tags: sql, triggers, insert

I have a table with a AutoIdentity column as its PK and a nvarchar column called "IdentificationCode". All I want is when inserting a new row, it will search the table for any preexisting IdentificationCode, and if any found roll back the transaction.

I have written the folowing trigger:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[Disallow_Duplicate_Ids] 
on [dbo].[tbl1]
for insert
as
if ((select COUNT(*) from dbo.tbl1 e , inserted i where e.IdentificationNo = i.IdentificationNo ) > 0)
begin
RAISERROR('Multiple Ids detected',16,1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
end
```

But when inserting new rows, it always triggers the rollback even if there is no such IdentificationCode.

Can any one help me please?

thanks

Comment: Could you not just define a `Unique constraint` on the NVARCHAR column. this would then cause the insert to fail if that code already exists in the DB. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Comment: That is a better option, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Qpirate mentions, you should probably put some sort of `UNIQUE` constraint on the column.  This is *probably* 'stronger' than using a trigger, as there's ways to disable those.
Also, the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) is considered an SQL anti-pattern - if possible, please always explicitly declare your joins.

I suspect that your error is because your trigger seems to be an `AFTER` trigger, and you check to see if there are *any* (non-zero) rows in the table; in other words, the trigger is (possibly) 'failing' the `INSERT` *because* it was `INSERT`ed.  Changing it to a `BEFORE` (or `INSTEAD OF`) trigger, or changing the count to `>= 2` may solve the problem.

Without seeing your insert statement, it's impossible to know for sure, but (especially if you're using a SP), you may be able to check for existence in the `INSERT` statement itself, and throw an error (or do something else) if the row isn't inserted.
For example, the following:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (identificationCode, *otherColumns*)
VALUES (@identificationCode, *otherColumns)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1'
                  FROM tbl1
                  WHERE identificationCode = @identificationCode)
```

Will return a code indicating 'row not found' (inserted, etc; on pretty much every system this is `SQLCODE = 100`) if `identificationCode` is already present.

Answer (score 0):

**Use EXISTS to check if the IdentificationCode already exist.**

```
If EXISTS (Select * from tbl1 where IdentificationCode = @IdentificationCode )
BEGIN
//do something
END
Else
BEGIN
//do something
END
```